# How to make Ajax request when click on Table row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a table and when I click on a row the `<TR>` element is having a class assigned "selected". Now I want to capture the content of the first `<TD>` element of that row (because it is an ID) and do an Ajax request, the response will be used to fill a form next to the table.

I can't write an `onClick` event in the `<TR>` html element, because the table is generated by another source, but I can see that the class get added and removed when click on a row. So i need to have it outside of the table html.

I am using Codeigniter as PHP Framework, but i am kinda new to jquery ajax function. thanks for help..

I have an [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpgsptov/)

```js
$("#testTable tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("select");
});



$("button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: './getMyData.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#testTable tr {
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.select {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-stripe" id="testTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>234</td>
          <td>Team 1</td>
          <td>2017-06-14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>254</td>
          <td>Team 2</td>
          <td>2017-06-14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>834</td>
          <td>Team 4</td>
          <td>2017-06-14</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Name from Ajaxcall" id="example-text-input">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">ID</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="ID from Ajaxcall" id="example-text-input">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Date</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Date from Ajaxcall" id="example-text-input">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> SOLVED

The CI Controller returned an array instead an Object, which I couldn't utilize with the below suggested code.

I changed my CI model like below:

```
public function get_detail($id){
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$sql = $this->db->query("select * from table where table_id=$id")->result();

$resultDetail = array();
foreach ($sql as $row){
$resultDetail[] = $row;
}        
echo json_encode($resultDetail);

}
```

This returned an prepared json object which I can select each individual item.

Comment: u havent echo anything here and what does
`$groups_array[] = array();` do ????????????

Comment: what does `$this->group_model->json_group_detail($group_id);` return ????

Comment: you should hv something like `echo json_encode($response_array)`;

Comment: did u try this `echo json_encode($groups['group_detail_json']);`

Comment: wired, when I do `get` in `$group_id = (int) $this->input->post('id');` then I do get a response, if I leave `post` it is a echo `null` and an empty `array`

Comment: I solved it. It was the Model causing the issue. I had to clean up the structure. But thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine :

```
$("#testTable").on('click','tr',function() {
          var id = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
          console.log(id);
          $(this).toggleClass("select");
$.ajax({
    url: './getMyData.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { id : id },
    success: function(result) {
      var jsondata = $.parseJSON(result);
       $("#name").val(jsondata.name);
       $("#uid").val(jsondata.id)
       $("#data").val(jsondata.date)
    }
  });



        });
```

on dynamic generated content by js binding works best.

Comment: hmm ok,.. but how is this doing an ajax call?

Comment: Almost, it throws an internal 500 Error. I guess it is because Codeigniter expects the number only not `id=number` is there a way to send only the plain number?

Comment: what are r u getting in your CI controller in $_POST array ?

Comment: I see in the console that the id = mynumber is parsed, but when i use it in my query it seems to be empty.

Comment: sorry m nt getting u, which query ? db ?
try putting echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; die();
in your controller and look at wat u get in server side.

Comment: empty array `array (size=0) empty`

Comment: It looks like that I am not sending `id = 38484` instead `id=38484` this means, the string is  `id=38484` instead `38484`

Comment: i ajax is fine...
what is your POST url ?

Comment: `url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Groups/json_group_detail/',`

Comment: try removing `dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',`

Comment: actually contentType ws causing the issue it ws telling what type of data its sending to the server is ws sending JSON
default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It is doing the ajax call fine. I took it out. But I can't echo the response into my html. It says the variable is undefined. I am using the CI controller variable which is returned from this call. Any idea how to reuse the json result?

Comment: u mean `result` is undefined ?? or ??

Comment: `Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: groups_array

Filename: Groups/group_list.php

Line Number: 3

Backtrace:`

Comment: when I do `<?php echo json_encode($groups_array); ?>`

Comment: ok, i added a div element and put the id you defined in your answer. But can i give each input element an id and assign individual json item to it?

Comment: sorry nt getting you.
if u hv php issue u cn post the controller code so that i cn hv a look.

Comment: sorry misleading you. All is fine, I did the php part wrong. Using your code `success: function(result) {
                  //$("#div1").html(result);
                  $("#div1").html(result);
                }` is doing what i need, but it is giving me the plain json in a div. Any way I can put a specific part like `"guests_actual": "10"` in an input with id `g_actual` ?

Comment: I want to fill my form values with the json response.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. But unfortunately this isn't assign the value. I have inspected the input field, but the `value` remain blank on click of the other items.

Comment: did u put the proper id's in the input fields `id="name" , id="date", id="uid"` ?

Comment: yes I did and I tried this `$("#test1").html(grp_detail_data.group_type);` there is nothing shown. I assume this has to do with the parse?

Comment: please post your scripts, like this it will go on forever.

Comment: ur input `id=grp_detail_group_name` but u use `#test` , it should be `#grp_detail_group_name` i think.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was #grp_detail_group_name before. I had an extra input with #test for testing. But still not doing it.

Comment: did u check console for errors ?

btw post ur controller method code too.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
var tdText = $('tr.select').find('td:first-child').text();
```

Through this selected `tr` will be searched. From there, find the `td` and get its text

Further, you could do this to solve your problem

https://jsfiddle.net/6oxLhkv8/

```
$("#testTable tr").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();

  $.ajax({
    url: './getMyData.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id: id}
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$('td.select td:first-child').text();` or `$('td.select').children().first().text();` to get the inner text of the desired row.

Note that you should only have 1 `td` with class `select` in your DOM.